Finding features with linear predictive power by maximizing a correlation; for binary classification problems; why isn't this working?
train-4.csv has 200000 rows and roughly 200 columns.  train-4.csv has as its first column, either the ground truth 0 or the ground truth 1.  aux-n.csv where n>0 is meant to store what happens when we apply the solution for train-4 in the algorithm.
In particular, I am trying to compete in the closed competition here:
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santander-customer-transaction-prediction
When I get the optimal bias coefficients and apply them to the test.csv, my accuracy is around 1/2, meaning that my answer is the same as if I had randomly guessed; very displeasing.
Here is my code so far:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Load training data
train_data_path = "G:\\My Drive\\bak 2024\\datasets\\Santander Customer Transaction Prediction\\train-4.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(train_data_path)

# Extract the first column of df
first_column = df.iloc[:, 0]

# Extract the remaining columns of df
remaining_columns = df.iloc[:, 1:]

def correlation_function(coefficients):
    dot_product_coefficients = remaining_columns.dot(coefficients)
    correlation = np.corrcoef(first_column, dot_product_coefficients)[0, 1]
    return -np.abs(correlation)  # Return scalar instead of array

# Generate initial guess for coefficients as random numbers between -1 and 1
np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
initial_guess = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, len(remaining_columns.columns))

# Minimize negative absolute correlation to maximize absolute correlation
result = minimize(correlation_function, initial_guess, method="Powell")

# Calculate the dot product of remaining_columns and optimal coefficients
optimal_coefficients = result.x
dot_product_coefficients = remaining_columns.dot(optimal_coefficients)

# Fit linear regression model
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(dot_product_coefficients.values.reshape(-1, 1), first_column)

# Apply best linear fit function to dot_product_coefficients
pf = model.predict(dot_product_coefficients.values.reshape(-1, 1))

# Apply threshold
t = 0.34
thresholded_values = np.where(pf >= t, 1, 0)

# Calculate accuracy
accuracy_ratio = np.mean(first_column == thresholded_values)

print("Accuracy ratio as a percent:", 100 * accuracy_ratio)

output_csv_path = "G:\\My Drive\\bak 2024\\datasets\\Santander Customer Transaction Prediction\\aux-11.csv"
thresholded_series = pd.Series(thresholded_values, name='thresholded_values')
thresholded_series.to_csv(output_csv_path, index=False)
print(f"Thresholded values exported to: {output_csv_path}")

With this, aux-11.csv just ends up being all 0's which is wrong. There should be some 0's and some 1's.
What can I do to make it right?  TIA
I have tried numerous things and I was expecting a prediction csv that would show what the training model is when applied to the test.csv.
I notice that seemingly nothing in the data makes use of test.csv....Hmm...
Update: I have tried to incorporate test.csv into my code so that the training is actually being applied to the test data whose ground truth answer we do not know.
Here it all is, some of this is a reiteration of what's above.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Load training data
train_data_path = "G:\\My Drive\\bak 2024\\datasets\\Santander Customer Transaction Prediction\\train-5.csv"
df_train = pd.read_csv(train_data_path)

# Extract the first column and remaining columns from training data
first_column = df_train.iloc[:, 0]
remaining_columns = df_train.iloc[:, 1:]

# Define the correlation function
def correlation_function(coefficients):
    dot_product_coefficients = remaining_columns.dot(coefficients)
    correlation = np.corrcoef(first_column, dot_product_coefficients)[0, 1]
    return -np.abs(correlation)

# Generate initial guess for coefficients as random numbers between -1 and 1
np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
initial_guess = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, remaining_columns.shape[1])

# Minimize negative absolute correlation to maximize absolute correlation
result = minimize(correlation_function, initial_guess, method="Powell")

# Calculate the dot product of remaining_columns and optimal_coefficients
dot_product_coefficients = remaining_columns.dot(result.x)

# Fit linear regression model
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(dot_product_coefficients.values.reshape(-1, 1), first_column)

# Load test data
test_data_path = "G:\\My Drive\\bak 2024\\datasets\\Santander Customer Transaction Prediction\\test-4.csv"
df_test = pd.read_csv(test_data_path)

# Ensure the test data has the same number of columns as the training data
if df_test.shape[1] - 1 != remaining_columns.shape[1]:
    raise ValueError(f"Test data should have {remaining_columns.shape[1]} features, but has {df_test.shape[1] - 1}")

# Extract remaining columns from test data
test_remaining_columns = df_test.iloc[:, 1:]

# Calculate the dot product for test data
test_dot_product_coefficients = test_remaining_columns.dot(result.x)

# Apply the linear model to get predicted values
predicted_values = model.predict(test_dot_product_coefficients.values.reshape(-1, 1))

# Apply threshold
t = 0.34
thresholded_values = np.where(predicted_values >= t, 1, 0)

# Ensure the output has the correct number of rows
if len(thresholded_values) != 199999:
    raise ValueError(f"The output should have 199999 rows, but has {len(thresholded_values)}")

# Create a DataFrame with the thresholded values
output_df = pd.DataFrame(thresholded_values, columns=["Prediction"])

# Save the updated test data to a new CSV file
output_path = "G:\\My Drive\\bak 2024\\datasets\\Santander Customer Transaction Prediction\\aux-18.csv"
output_df.to_csv(output_path, index=False)

# Print results
print("Predicted values with threshold applied:")
print(thresholded_values)

